# Find MAX(date) from HTML5 indexedDB

Tags: sql, database, indexeddb

I'm currently using indexdDB to store offline data of some records in a sales store. The store has columns such as id, shopname, and lastsaledate. I would like some help performing the same operation as the following SQL statement using indexedDB:

```
SELECT MAX(LastSaleDate) FROM Sales;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or you are just asking for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: I input all the data into an array, and then try to find **MAX** from that array. but all in vain because of **DATE DataType**. :-)

Now I'm going to try something different. ;-)
@Boris

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have an index for the lastsaledate property, e.g. when upgrading the database do:

```
store.createIndex('by_lastsaledate', 'lastsaledate');
```

When querying, use a reverse cursor ('prev') and null range (i.e. all records):

```
var store = transaction.objectStore('records');
var index = store.index('by_lastsaledate');
var request = index.openCursor(/*query*/null, /*direction*/'prev');
request.onsuccess = function() {
  var cursor = request.result;
  if (cursor) {
    console.log('max date is: ' + cursor.key);
  } else {
    console.log('no records!');
  }
};
```

Comment: what if the data already has been in some **live dataBase**. And I'm syncing data from that **live DB** and inserting it to the **indexed DB** at client end!

Comment: You can create an index on an existing store by bumping the version number and creating the index in the upgradeneeded event handler. The spec has examples in the introduction https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#introduction - look for "Version 2 introduces a new index of books by year"